# Include subclasses in to_xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, inheritance, sti

following problem:
I am generating an xml document of my database-model. Inheritance via STI.

My Model:

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :properties
    belongs_to :relationship
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Extensions::UUID
    belongs_to :entity, :foreign_key => 'property_uid'

  #just there for xml-creation
    has_one :enum, :foreign_key => 'attribute_uid'
    has_many :entities, :foreign_key => 'relationship_uid'
end

class Attribute < Property
    has_one :enum, :foreign_key => 'attribute_uid'
end

class Relationship < Property
has_many :entities, :foreign_key => 'relationship_uid'
end
```

To generate the XML I call `Entity.to_xml(:skip_instruct => true, :include => Entity.xml_includes)`

in Entity the `self.includes` looks like this:

```
  def self.xml_includes
    includes = {}
    includes[:properties] = { :include => :enum, :include => :entities } 
    return includes
  end
```

this currently works, but seems to be just a workaround, because the `Property` has to have the same relationships as the Classes that inherit from `Property`.

What I'm looking for is an algorithm that looks whether the current property is an `Attribute` or a `Relationship` and the to include the corresponding relationships.